# Visual Studio 2013 update 3 problems

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

After installing VS 2013 Upgrade 3, I get errors for loading a bunch of packages.
1) VS Package
2) PowerShellToolsPackage
3)Microsoft.Lightswitch.VSIntegration.Project
       .ProjectUpdateDelegatorPackage

Right now I'm dealing with #1, VS Package.
It says "The 'VSPackage' package did not load correctly.

```
Activity Log says:
    <entry>
        <record>315</record>
        <time>2014/09/15 17:32:43.190</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [VSPackage]</description>
    <guid>{1A4EFADE-F6B2-4490-A2EF-21D5F3D1C8E0}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft   Visual    Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\hjkzccc5.cqc\Microsoft.AppInsights.GettingStarted.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
```

This happens not when I open VS itself, but when I open the solution.

Comment: So, did my answer help? I'm kind curious, since I never heard anything else about it.

Answer (score 7):

I started having this error earlier today as well, and found that it has to do with the "Release Management for Visual Studio 2013" package. Once I uninstalled that, everything went back to normal. I only installed it in the first place because Visual Studio wouldn't shut up about it in the notifications pane. Anyway, if you have it installed and you're not actively using it, try uninstalling it and see if that clears up the error for you.

1. Go to Tools -> Extensions & Updates
2. Find "Release Management for Visual Studio 2013"
3. Click "Uninstall"
4. Restart Visual Studio

Hopefully that fixes it for you, too.

Comment: I upvoted this, and that is the reason I am commenting. Because I can't just say 'plus one' now. Anyway... This may not be 'the fix' but it fixed it for me. That's what I get for blindly installing a extension because MS prompted me to.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after installing SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013, having applied Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 a week earlier.  Gave Mel’s suggestion a go, but no joy.  The rest of the error said

> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the
>   installation of another extension. You can get more information by
>   examining the file
>   'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

What worked for me:

1. Opened ActivityLog.xml, searched for the ERROR entry. I opened it in
   Internet Explorer 11 and the relevant lines were handily highlighted
   in red.
2. Extracted the GUID and searched the registry for it. The first three
   were just references, the fourth was the actual VS
   package. You may be able to hone in a bit quicker if you search from
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Packages.
3. Uninstalled the package from VS2013. I wasn’t using it, maybe I
   could have simply disabled it instead. Anyway, bingo! No error when 
   project loads.

In my case, the problem package was [Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/82367b81-3f97-4de1-bbf1-eaf52ddc635a). The conflict related to Visual Studio Online (VSO). If that's the case for you, note that the package web page says:

> If you have Visual Studio Update 3 or later and you still want to use
>   the VSO portal, you have to uninstall version 2 of these Tools before
>   installing this version.

I'd had version 2.5 installed, possibly from when I installed some Azure stuff a couple of weeks before.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I found a workaround in the following website:

Workaround to include Deployment Project

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1158138/resourcemanagerpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly

## 1. Close Visual Studio

## 2. Open Windows PowerShell console in admin mode

## 3. Find and Uninstall the Azure Resource Manager and Common Azure Tools Components (Run as Administrator)

gwmi win32_product | ? {$*.PackageName -Like "*ResourceManager.Setup*" -or $*.PackageName -Like "*DeploymentProject*" -or $*.PackageName -Like "*CommonAzureTools*"} | % {$id = $*.IdentifyingNumber ; Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec" -ArgumentList " /x $id /qb" -Wait}

## 4. Repair each of the matching Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 20XX - vX.X" (You can also do this from ARP)

gci "$env:ProgramData\Package Cache\MicrosoftAzureTools.*.exe" -Recurse | % {. $_.FullName /modify}

Answer (score 0):

The solution that ended up working for me was uninstalling Xamarin (via Programs And Features), repairing VS, and re-installing Xamarin (found this solution elsewhere, but don't remember where).